# valgrind: –-tool=memcheck: command not found

Tags: unicode, terminal, valgrind

I ran this command in terminal, with the correct directory specified (also compiled with executable available):

```
valgrind –-tool=memcheck –-leak-check=yes ./somefile
```

An error is returned:

```
valgrind: –-tool=memcheck: command not found
```

Is this an issue with my installation of Valgrind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
–-tool
```

is wrong. It should be

```
--tool
```

The difference: In your version the first character is not a minus, but a `U+2013 EN DASH`.

That's why valgrind doesn't recognize it as the start of an option, but thinks `–-tool=memcheck` is the name of a command to run (with `–-leak-check=yes ./somefile` being the command line arguments).